# Отключить выпадающее меню

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap, opencart

Добрый день.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в этом шаблоне отключить выпадающее меню в принципе на всех страницах. Мне достаточно в меню только названий категорий (ссылки) без выпадающих подкатегорий.
Вот этот самый шаблон:
https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/54714.html
Или направьте меня целенаправленно - в какую сторону копать, что и в каком файле редактировать.
Просто отключить jQuery, к сожалению, не вариант)

Comment: Копай html файлы и удаляй, что трудного?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но... Это mvc и там нет в таком прямом понимании index.html. Я пока что не имею большого опыта, поэтому и прошу совета.

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу - какая версия opencart?

Comment: Спасибо тем, кто пытался помочь. Отключил выпадающее меню радикально - отключил загрузку superfish.js

Answer (score 0):

В папке сайта, по пути `/catalog/view/theme/theme574/stylesheet/`, в файле `stylesheet.css` найдитестрочку `.nav__primary .menu > li > ul li` (строка 1373). Добавьте к свойствам данного селектора `display:none!important;`. Это визуально скроет выпадающее меню, но оно продолжит генерироваться в файле представления